# What types are hash values and can i use comparison operators?

Tags: javascript, firefox, hash, firefox-addon, operators

I'm developing a firefox extension and i'd like to know:

1. After i obtain a hash value from a string, what data type is that value?
2. Can i use comparison operators with them?

So what i would like to do is compare two hash values and see if one is e.g. higher than the other. Just like comparing if `5 >= 4`. Is this possible? To treat hash values like integers?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I'm creating an extension for mozila firefox, so it's javascript but it uses (if not mistaken) classes written in C++

Comment: Well, you could order hash values, but the result would typically be different to the order you get when you sort the hashed objects. Why would you want to order hash values?

Comment: I think i got it, thanks. I am applying Chord protocol and that protocol needs to place an ip+port on a circle, and i need to know between which other 2 ip+port nodes is my current node. So i hash ip+port and place them around the circle according to their values ...let's say hash1 < hash 2 < hash 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is one of the most popular hashing algorithms. It gives you a hex-decimal number from a string that can be used for comparison with reasonable safety. For JavaScript you might try [crypto-js](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) but you can easily find many other implementations on the net.

Answer (score 1):

In a Firefox add-on you should be using [nsICryptoHash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsICryptoHash). For example, if you want to hash a string using the MD5 algorithm you would use the following function:

```
function toMD5(str)
{
  // Convert string to an array of bytes
  var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(str);

  // Create MD5 hash
  var hashEngine = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/security/hash;1"]
                             .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsICryptoHash);
  hashEngine.init(hashEngine.MD5);
  hashEngine.update(array, array.length);
  return hashEngine.finish(true);
}

alert(toMD5("test"));  // Displays: 8dP/hEMpdzKGLfIdxOVyYg==
```

Note that this returns the base64-encoded hash value. Use `finish(false)` to get the raw (binary) hash value.